# Почему не возвращается значение из функции?

Tags: javascript

Написал рекурсивную функцию, которая вызывает сама себя, пока не достигнуто условие. По достижению условия, функция должна вернуть результат:

```js
function f(arg) {
    if(arg < 3) {
        arg++;
        f(arg);
    }
    else {
        console.log(arg);
        return arg;
    }
}

console.log(f(1));

// 3
// undefined
```

В данный момент `return arg` возвращает `undefined`. В чем проблема?

Comment: В первой ветви if-a `return f(arg);` ?

Comment: Не обратил внимание на `return`. Все работает, спасибо! Напиши ответом - выберу, как решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возврат с помощью return происходит только на предпоследний уровень рекурсии, а на остальных пропущен. Нужно добавить возврат в первую часть if

```
if(arg < 3) {
    arg++;
    return f(arg);
}
...
```